# Null pointer error while using sessionfactory on Hibernate 4 with Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I'm struggling to figure out the exact problem, why the Null Pointer Error is thrown for Hibernate sessionFactory when I try to Auto wire sessionFactory from spring bean xml. Could somebody please help me out fix this. I'm new to Spring and deploying the app on Jboss server

Here is the Spring-Config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.kp.db.dao.impl" />


    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebm" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is Hiberante.cfg.xml which I placed in webcontent folder

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="org/kp/db/model/Actioncode.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="org.kp.db.model.TblEBMFieldDetails"/>
    <mapping class="org.kp.db.model.TbleOLI"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the DAO class in which I'm trying to access the sessionFactory is

```
package org.kp.db.dao.impl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.kp.db.dao.ActionCodeDao;
import org.kp.db.model.Actioncode;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@Repository
public class ActionCodeDaoImpl implements ActionCodeDao{

    @Override
    public String[] getActionCodes() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


    @Autowired(required=true)
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public String getActionCode(int id) {

        //ApplicationContext context;

        Session  session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Actioncode actionCode=null;
        actionCode = (Actioncode)session.get(Actioncode.class, 1);

        return actionCode.getActionName();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you also add the stacktrace to your post?

Comment: Check if sessionFactory and session are null.

Comment: Hi yeah  SessionFactory is null hence its throwing null pointer exception. I wonder what will happen if mysql connection is not present, at this time will there be sessionFactory null and how can i verify, please find the server log

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.kp.db.dao.impl.ActionCodeDaoImpl.getActionCode(ActionCodeDaoImpl.java:49) [classes:]
 at org.kp.business.Actions.getActionCode(Actions.java:24) [classes:]
 at org.springf.SprngBean.sayHello(SprngBean.java:13) [classes:]
 at org.kp.back.MyBackingBean.getSrt(MyBackingBean.java:19) [classes:]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]

Comment: is `org.springf.SprngBean.sayHello` your custom class? If so can we see it? Also can we see `org.kp.back.MyBackingBean.getSrt`

Comment: Hi MyBackingBean is a jsf backing bean which calls springBean which can call somany other spring beans(my business logic) and of the business bean is kpAction which uses DaoImpl to connect to Data base and fetch data @ Named("backing")
public class MyBackingBean implements Serializable{
 private String srt;
 @ Inject
 SprngBean myBean;
 public String getSrt() {
 String text=myBean.sayHello();
  srt=text;
  return srt;
 }
 public void setSrt(String srt) {
  this.srt = srt;
 }
 public class SprngBean {
 @ Inject
 Actions kpAction;
 public String sayHello(){
  return kpAction.getActionCode();}
}

Comment: @Named ("kpAction")
public class Actions {
    
    
    
    public String getActionCode(){
        
        ActionCodeDao action =new ActionCodeDaoImpl();
        String str = action.getActionCode(1);
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue, instead of accessing the object I used the getter method and it worked, not sure what is the real concept behind it.

```
public String getActionCode(int id) {

    //ApplicationContext context;

    Session  session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Actioncode actionCode=null;
    actionCode = (Actioncode)session.get(Actioncode.class, 1);

    return actionCode.getActionName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Named ("kpAction") 
public class Actions { 
    public String getActionCode() { 
        ActionCodeDao action =new ActionCodeDaoImpl(); 
        String str = action.getActionCode(1); System.out.println(str); return str; 
    } 
}
```

When you run this line of code: `ActionCodeDao action =new ActionCodeDaoImpl();` you get an object that is not managed by Spring and therefore will not contain the autowired dependencies.

I would say that is why you saw the null pointer.

However you say you have fixed it now, not sure if you inadvertantly changed this as well, if not im not sure how youve fixed it :)