# How to avoid SonarLint UnusedPrivateMethod when instantiating Spring components?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, jvm, sonarlint

In a basic Spring Boot app I have this component:

```
@Component
public class TheComponent {
    public String getKey() {return "value";}
}
```

used by a service. If I design my service like this:

```
@Service
public class TheService { 

    @Autowired
    private TheComponent theComponent;

    private final String keyValue = theComponent.getKey();

    private TheService() {}
}
```

then Spring Boot doesn't build because `theComponent` triggers a `NullPointerException`.

If I design it like this:

```
@Service
public class TheService {

    private String keyValue;

    private TheService(TheComponent theComponent) {
        keyValue = theComponent.getKey();
    }
}
```

then SonarLint tells me that I should *Remove this unused private "TheService" constructor*.

Is there a solution that would suit both Spring and SonarLint, using a private constructor ?

Comment: The issue is why TheComponent can't be auto wired, do you use component scan or how do you set it as bean?

Comment: Sorry I can't answer your question. I can only say that I used Spring initializr without changing any config. I assume it can't be autowired because `keyValue` initialization happens before autowiring ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16561425/3790512)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate your constructor with:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

You can also use it on class level to suppress all warnings.

Comment: This means that SonarLint isn't smart enough to see that this method is actually used. Is it the case ?

Comment: Sometimes linting tools cannot be blamed. For example hibernate uses no args constructors by reflection. From the outside it might not be visible.

Comment: This will certainly suppress all the sonarlint warnings